# Prevent line break within date (Month - Year) of \cventry

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

I'm trying to make my CV using `modercv` `classic` theme.
When I type dates (Month-Year) I don't want that it makes a line break between Month and Year in the beginning of the line.

I'm using this LaTeX code:

```
\section{Projets Académiques}
  \cventry{Décembre2016}{Recherche Opérationnelle}{Problème du voyageur de 
  commerce avec Python}{}{}{\newline{}}
```

How can I fix it please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

The width of the "date" field within `\cventry` is dependent on the length `\hintscolumnwidth`. If you want things to stick together, you can use a tie (`Décembre~2016`), but this would cause overfull boxes:

[image]

```
\section{Projets Académiques}

\cventry
  {Décembre~2016}
  {Recherche Opérationnelle}
  {Problème du voyageur de commerce avec Python}
  {}{}{}
```

Instead, set the appropriate width within your preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\settowidth{\hintscolumnwidth}{Décembre 2016}

\begin{document}

\section{Projets Académiques}

\cventry
  {Décembre 2016}
  {Recherche Opérationnelle}
  {Problème du voyageur de commerce avec Python}
  {}{}{}

\end{document}
```